# Is there a Maven repository for Apache Spark Release Candidates?

Tags: maven, apache-spark

I want to add a release candidate of Apache Spark as a Maven dependency to my project. Is there a repository I can reference?

(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11 does not have RCs)

Comment: I don't think that there is some repository with RC versions. However, it's very simple to build Spark on your own machine

Comment: I know, but it takes about 15 min for each developer on our team. Also, I'd like to use the corporate artifactory we have in place.

Comment: So maybe Jenkins + custom Artifactory or Nexus?

Comment: Yes, if there really isn't a public repo I'll have to go with that. Thanks!

Comment: What about using the state in Maven Central: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.apache.spark%22 and the project does not offer RC's ? You might ask on the dev list of spark if they produce SNAPSHOT's ?

Comment: Thanks, @khmarbaise! However, Maven Central only provides `v2.1.1`, I need `v2.2.0-RC3` or `RC4`, since that contains a fix I need.

Comment: Try looking at the dev list thread: http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/VOTE-Apache-Spark-2-2-0-RC4-td21677.html. Specifically they release to an apache staging repository (https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/orgapachespark-1241/) which appears to be using nexus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As assaf-mendelson wrote, there is

> https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/

for Release Candidates, specifically

> https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/orgapachespark-1241/

for Spark v2.2.0. And then there also is

> https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/

for current snapshots.